# Write an SQL query to print details of the Workers whose FIRST_NAME ends with ‘h’ and contains six alphabets?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
    WORKER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRST_NAME CHAR(25),
    LAST_NAME CHAR(25),
    SALARY INT(15),
    JOINING_DATE DATETIME,
    DEPARTMENT CHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO Worker 
    (WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) VALUES
        (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR'),
        (002, 'Niharika', 'Verma', 80000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (003, 'Vishal', 'Singhal', 300000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR'),
        (004, 'Amitabh', 'Singh', 500000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (005, 'Vivek', 'Bhati', 500000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (006, 'Vipul', 'Diwan', 200000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Account'),
        (007, 'Satish', 'Kumar', 75000, '14-01-20 09.00.00', 'Account'),
        (008, 'Geetika', 'Chauhan', 90000, '14-04-11 09.00.00', 'Admin');
```

I'm looking for a way to get the desired result of the following question using the AND function.

Any solutions on the same would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try, what is your concrete question here? You can use RIGHT and LENGTH here or LIKE and LENGTH. Or even FIRST_NAME LIKE '_____h'

Comment: @Jonas I did the following to get the result, however I'm looking for a way to get the result using the AND function. Is there a way, I can use two functions and come to the desired result?That's my question.

<code> Select * from Worker where FIRST_NAME like '_____h'; <code>

Comment: @Jonas Thanks I got the answer to my question from your fiddles.

Comment: "_six alphabets_" - do you mean six letters, or six characters?

Comment: Exactly six, or six or more?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, give us sample data _and the matching expected result_...

Comment: @jarlh what's the difference? and it means that the FIRST_NAME should contain exactly 6 letters.

Comment: Someone else could mean 1wer23/fff#&#¤ has six letters.

Comment: The difference is that the answer I gave would select for example '12345h' as valid first name although it contains one letter only. I assumed such cases will not happen in your table because it likely always contains "valid" first names. But if you want to be really precise and clean (and this is often necessary when writing SQL!), you should be clearer about your requirements. That's one of the reasons why I asked you what your concrete question is in my first comment.

Comment: And first names like 'Frank-Walter' also have a different length than number of letters (although it is unlikey the total length of such names will be 6) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * from Wroker
WHERE RIGHT(FIRST_NAME, 1) = 'h' 
      AND LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest option is likely this (will become bad to read if the length increases from 6 to 10, 15 etc. due to many underscores):

```
SELECT *
FROM Worker
WHERE 
  FIRST_NAME LIKE '_____h'
```

Especially for a high length, I would avoid this and use `LIKE` and `LENGTH`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Worker
WHERE 
  LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) = 6 AND
  FIRST_NAME LIKE '%h'
```

Another similar option is `RIGHT` and `LENGTH`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Worker
WHERE 
  LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) = 6 AND
  RIGHT(FIRST_NAME,1) = 'h'
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/C4HXlEX-)

Note: The answer assumes you just want to check whether exactly six characters appear. Edit your question - and if you know how - also the query - if this is not sufficient and you need to exactly check for example for six letters instead (ignoring spaces, digits etc.) or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do it using `SUBSTRING` to extract from the sixth character and check if equal **h** :

```
SELECT * from Worker
WHERE SUBSTRING(FIRST_NAME, 6) = 'h'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Worker                                                         
Where FIRST_NAME like "%h" and length(FIRST_NAME)=6
```

[Take reference from image for the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCcIx.png)